# not able to add TwilioConversationsClient

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, cocoapods, twilio

i am adding  `TwilioConversationsClient (~> 0.25.0)`  using pod but not getting this error . i am using swift .
**[!] Unable to find a specification for `TwilioConversationsClient (~> 0.25.0)`** 
what is this error .how to solve this.

here is the  link https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/sdks

Comment: Did you add the source to your Podfile? What does your complete Podfile look like?

Comment: yes i  have added source like  pod 'TwilioCommon', source: 'https://github.com/twilio/cocoapod-specs'
    pod 'TwilioConversationsClient', source: 'https://github.com/twilio/cocoapod-specs'